# Call a function inside (window).resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize, jquery-pagescroller

For my site, I inizialized `pageScroller` by a function that changes scrollOffset depending on the window width.

```
jQuery(function offset_value(){
if ($(window).width() < 960)  {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '#nav',
        scrollOffset: -40
        });         
        });
} else {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
        navigation: '#nav',
        scrollOffset: -195
        });
        });
}
});
```

However, I need also to reload this function at window resize. For example, if the user rotate the smartphone, the window width changes. So, I added this code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    offset_value()
}).resize();
```

The problem is that the `scrollOffset` value does not change at window resize, as if the `offset_value` function was not called.

A (not so elegant) solution is to refresh the entaire page at window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
location.reload();
return;
});
```

but I don't like one has to wait for the site to reload at the rotation of the device.

**Where is the problem? Any suggestion?**

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried putting your `pageScroller` in a `$(window).load` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here is that your function declaration makes it inaccessible from outside:

```
jQuery(function offset_value() { ... });
```

This declares an anonymous function which can only be referenced by `offset_value` from the function's own body.

To fix this, you must declare the function outside:

```
function offset_value()
{
    ...
}

jQuery(offset_value); // run on document ready
```

You can also remove the `$(document).read()` because that's already done when you use `jQuery(fn)`.

#### Update

To reinitialise the plugin you need to reset the global `pageScroller`:

```
pageScroller = {};
$('body').pageScroller({ ... });
```

Comment: Done, but unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. `scrollOffset` is defined by the function only when the page is loaded, and I can't change it at window resize. This make me crazy!

Comment: I use pagescroller.lite.js, that is the free version of the code

Comment: @this.is.not.a.nick I've found a possible fix; you have to reset a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need document ready handler which is there inside the function:

```
jQuery(function offset_value(){
if ($(window).width() < 960)  {
   // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
    navigation: '#nav',
    scrollOffset: -40
    });
 } else {
   // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('body').pageScroller({
    navigation: '#nav',
    scrollOffset: -195
    });}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use document-ready handler in your function. Also I would recommend you to create a function and pass it to *document-ready handler* and *window-resize handler*

Use

```
//Create a function    
function offset_value() {
    if($(window).width() < 960) {
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
            navigation: '#nav',
            scrollOffset: -40
        });
    } else {
        // initiate page scroller plugin
        $('body').pageScroller({
            navigation: '#nav',
            scrollOffset: -195
        });
    }
};
//Pass function reference to document-ready handler and window resize
$(document).ready(offset_value);
$(window).resize(offset_value).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code with your suggestions but the problem remains the same.